# How do I find the diameter of a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, performance, diameter-protocol

hey i'm looking for an algorithm to find the diameter (the longest shortest path) in an undirected unweighted graph G=(V,E).

the best solution i found was to run BFS |V| times, running time: O(|V|*(|v|+|E|)).
can anybody think of a more efficient solution?
even if it's only a bit more efficient i'd like to hear your ideas !

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

There is some very recent work by [Crescenzi et al. on “On Computing the Diameter of Real-world Undirected Graphs.” (2013)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397512008687) that proposes an algorithm that runs in `O(V*E)` worst case, but `O(V)` in a lot of real-world applications (I assume that means sparse graphs).

Comment: There is some more information here: http://amici.dsi.unifi.it/lasagne/?page_id=43. For more detail you will have to read the paper.